# JSF and css don't work

Tags: css, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am using JSF 2.2 in a regular dynamic web project , i have included a css code in a xhtml page.

Web-content  WEB-CONTENT  Ressources  css  style.ss

in my index.xhtml i used this code

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="WEB-INF/Ressources/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

but the css doesn't work

Comment: have you tried `href="/Ressources/css/style.css"`?

Comment: yes , but that's not working .

Comment: Why don't you use the css JSF tag to do that : `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />` ?

Answer (score 0):

Files inside `WEB-INF` aren't accessible from the outside. You have to place them in some other directory. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="#{request.contextPath}/Ressources/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. If you are using maven or not sure where the css file is just open the war file with winzip and see what the css path is..